# good jquery/javascript date and time picker for this format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I can't find a good jquery date and time that displays my selected date and time like this
 
 `11-Aug-2010 12:30:38`. Any good one you have seen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.w3visions.com/2009/04/date-time-picker-with-jquery-ui-datepicker/

http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

One of these link helps you

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest, but this works:

```
function getDateStr()
{
  var d=new Date();
  var m=new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
  return len(d.getDate())+'-'+m[d.getMonth()]+'-'+d.getFullYear()+' '+len(d.getHours())+':'+len(d.getMinutes())+':'+len(d.getSeconds());
}

function len(s)
{
  if((s+' ').length<3)
  {
    return '0'+s;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Call getDateStr() to receive the date in that format.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/ has the best datepicker IMO!